# Error message - Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: sql, distinct, alias

I have this SQL Syntax but it's not working and receive this error:

> "#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias".

Could you help me?

```
SELECT *
FROM produse_comenzi
JOIN comenzi ON comenzi.id_comanda = produse_comenzi.id_comanda
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura FROM facturi)
ON facturi.id_comanda = comenzi.id_comanda
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second join you are using a subquery but you haven't given the result an alias, i.e. something to identify the result by

```
SELECT *
  FROM produse_comenzi
  JOIN comenzi 
    ON comenzi.id_comanda = produse_comenzi.id_comanda
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura FROM facturi) -- has no alias
    ON facturi.id_comanda = comenzi.id_comanda
```

you should do

```
SELECT *
  FROM produse_comenzi
  JOIN comenzi 
    ON comenzi.id_comanda = produse_comenzi.id_comanda
  JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura, id_comanda FROM facturi) AS facturi
    ON facturi.id_comanda = comenzi.id_comanda
```

Comment: thank you, but now I have this error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'facturi.id_comanda' in 'on clause'

Comment: my guess is you need to also select the `id_comanda` column from `facturi`, have edited for this. if this doesn't work please update or ask another question providing the tables and how they should be joined.

Answer (score 0):

You must add an alias to each subquery that's being treated as a table:

```
SELECT *
FROM produse_comenzi
JOIN comenzi ON comenzi.id_comanda = produse_comenzi.id_comanda
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura FROM facturi) x
ON x.id_comanda = comenzi.id_comanda
```

Here I have named the result set `x` and referred to that in the join condition. You can change "x" to whatever you like.

Comment: thank you, but now I have this error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'x.id_comanda' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

(there is a need in SQL to distinguish between different Resultset from selects)

```
SELECT * 
FROM produse_comenzi AS table_1  
JOIN comenzi AS table_2  
ON table_2.id_comanda = table_1.id_comanda  
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT numar_factura FROM facturi AS table_3)  
ON table_3.id_comanda = table_2.id_comanda
```